# OpenMP questions

Tags: c++, class, openmp

I want to parallelize a loop in a class member function. However there are two errors in the code:

```
class myclass  
{  
public:  

int _k;  

void f(int nb_examples, int nb_try)  
{  
      int i;  
      int ks[nb_try];  
      // assignment to elements in ks  
      omp_set_num_threads(_nb_threads);  
    #pragma omp parallel shared(ks) private(i, _k) // error: ‘myclass::_k’ is not a variable in clause ‘private’  
      {  
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait  
        for(i=0; i < nb_try; i ++){  
          _k = ks[i];  
          if (_k > nb_examples)  break;// error: break statement used with OpenMP for loop  
          // operations on _k  
        }  
      }   
}  
}
```

How to explain these errors and solve the problems? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second error, The OpenMP specification doesn't allow you to break out of a parallel for loop, or throw exceptions, because of the parallel nature. Instead, see the workaround solution on this blog: http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/06/29/breaking-out-of-loops-in-openmp/

For the first error, took me a while to dig up what is actually going on - I think this explains it:

> Private variables must not have
>   reference type, since it will cause
>   concurrent shared memory access.
>   Although the variables will be
>   private, the variables will still
>   address the same memory fragment.
>   Class instances declared as private
>   must have explicit copy constructor,
>   since an instance containing
>   references will be copied incorrectly
>   otherwise.

from http://www.viva64.com/content/articles/parallel-programming/?f=32_OpenMP_traps.html&lang=en&content=parallel-programming

Basically I don't *think* you can use class-level variables as private without making copies of them. Is there any reason you can't use a variable within the scope of your function?

Comment: Thanks! I saw varialbles defined outside the parallel region can be declared as private, but why not here? Is there any workaround for the first error?

Comment: Edited my post - is there any reason you can't bring int _k into the method? Does it work if you do?